# Triple Integrals vs Double Integrals

Tags: calculus

If a double integral represents a volume in a 3 dimensional space

what does a triple integral represent?

what would be a real world example of a triple integral?

this isn't a homework question, I'm just curious what it actually represents

Comment: Let's say the temperature in a room is varying, so it's a function of three variables. Then the average temperature in the room can be given in terms of a triple integral.

Comment: I see, so for example: pressure, room size, and another factor, would represent the three variables in the equation that are responsible to the overall temperature?

Comment: I would not say that a double integral represents volume. A double integral is referring to a two-dimensional object, so it represents  the total mass of a 2D object with varying density.

Similarly, a single integral does not represent area. It is integrating along a line, so it represents the total mass of a wire (the line) with varying density.

Comment: A double integral inherently represents an "area" and a triple integral inherently represents a "volume".  Whether those words actually make sense depends on the function you are integrating.  One of the worst things they (used to) teach is that the integral (single integral) represents the "area under the curve"--this isn't what an integral is.  And I say "used to" because I know for a fact that the AP Calculus curriculum has explicitly shifted from saying this to saying that the integral is an "accumulator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if we're using physics as an example, I would look at the [Divergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement):

$$
\int_V \left(\vec{\nabla}\circ \vec{f}\right)dV = \oint_{\partial V} \vec{f}\circ d\vec{A}
$$

Here $\int_V$ is the integral over some volume and $\oint_{\partial V}$ is the integral over the closed boundary of that volume.  One place where this is particularly important in physics is the electrostatic force or Gauss's Law (which is why the divergence theorem is sometimes referred to as Gauss's theorem).  The equation from Maxwell's equations which describes the electrostatic force is:

$$
\vec{\nabla}\circ \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$

Here $\vec{E}$ is the electric field and $\rho$ is the charge density (this is *not* a constant and would, in general, vary over three dimensional space).  Now, I'm not going to actually *use* the divergence theorem, rather just show the two different integrals as an example of a triple and double integral.

Let's take the example of a uniformly charged sphere of charge density $\rho_0$.  It can be shown that the electric field *inside* of the sphere is given by:

$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0}\vec{r}
$$

Where the origin is taken to be the center of the sphere.  According to Gauss's Law (and the divergence theorem):

$$
\int_V \left(\vec{\nabla}\circ \vec{E}\right)dV = \oint_{\partial V} \vec{E}\circ d\vec{A}
$$

Here let's take $V$ to be the entire sphere of radius $R$.  Now, we're only going to be able to do this in spherical coordinates, so just take my word for now that the [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Spherical_coordinates) is:

$$
\vec{\nabla} \circ \left(f( r)\hat{r}\right) = 2\frac{f(r)}{r} + \frac{d f}{d r} \\
\vec{\nabla} \circ \vec{E} = \frac{2\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0} + \frac{\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0} = \frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}
$$

Which gives the following volume integral over the entire sphere:

\begin{align}
\iiint_V \frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}dV =& \frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}\int\limits_0^R\int\limits_0^\pi \int\limits_0^{2\pi}r^2\sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi dr \\
=& 2\pi\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}\int\limits_0^R\int\limits_0^\pi r^2 \sin(\phi)d\phi dr \\
=& 4\pi\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}\int\limits_0^R r^2dr \\
=& \frac{4 \pi R^3}{3}\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}
\end{align}

Now let's look at the surface integral.  First the boundary of the sphere has $r = R$ (a constant) and the $d\vec{A}$ always points in the direction of $\vec{r}$ so we have $d\vec{A} = dA\hat{r}$.  Now we have $\vec{E}(r)\hat{r} \circ d\vec{A} = E(r)dA$ (again, you can find dA in spherical coordinates [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates)):

\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial V} \vec{E}\circ d\vec{A} =& \frac{\rho_0}{3\epsilon_0}R\cdot R^2\int\limits_0^\pi\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi \\
=& 2\pi\frac{R^3}{3}\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0} \int_0^\pi \sin(\phi)d\phi \\
=& 4\pi\frac{R^3}{3}\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0} = \frac{4\pi R^3}{3}\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}
\end{align}

So you can see they are equal (because I used Gauss's Law to find the correct electric field in the first place), but more importantly you can see the use of a double and triple integral and that the triple integral was over a volume and the double integral was over a surface (an area).

Answer (score 2):

The volume integral of some random three dimensional figure $A$ parametrized by the equation $f(x,y,z)=f(\mathbf{x})$ is
$$\iiint_AdV$$
As an example in physics (quantum mechanics of a point particle), if $\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)$ is a wavefunction, i.e., the amplitude for a quantum particle to be at point $\mathbf{x}$ at time $t$, then the momentum amplitude is
$$\Psi(\mathbf{p},t)=\int\exp\left(\dfrac{-i\mathbf{p\cdot x}}{\hbar}\right)\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)d^3\mathbf{x}$$
Similarly, if $K(\mathbf{x}_b,t_b;\mathbf{x}_a,t_a)$ is the path integral, then
$$\Psi(\mathbf{x}_b,t_b)=\int K(\mathbf{x}_b,t_b;\mathbf{x}_a,t_a)\Psi(\mathbf{x}_a,t_a)d^3\mathbf{x}_a$$
You can also take three-dimensional integrals in momentum space, obtaining integrals of the form 
$$\int f(\mathbf{p})d^3\mathbf{p}$$
As an example, if $\Psi(\mathbf{p},t)$ is a wavefunction, i.e., the amplitude for a quantum particle to has momentum $\mathbf{p}$ at time $t$, then the momentum amplitude is
$$\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)=\int\exp\left(\dfrac{+i\mathbf{p\cdot x}}{\hbar}\right)\Psi(\mathbf{p},t)\dfrac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}$$
Where the term $(2\pi\hbar)^3$ comes up due to the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: I don't really see how this addresses the question at all.  And I'm not sure I agree with your first statement.  $V$ is the "figure" (the region in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and $f(x, y, z)$ is the function to be integrated over the volume--the differential you are integrating is $dS = f(x, y, z)dV$.

Comment: @Jared I apologize. I have edited my answer.